# How to add EditText value to ListView using BaseAdapter by clicking Button

Tags: android, android-listview

i am new to android,help with the code how add EditText value to ListView using BaseAdapter by clicking Button.
when i enter value in EditText and by clicking Add Button, value must place in ListViw(ListView must have BaseAdapter only)

ListDataActivity.java

```
public class ListDataActivity {
String myData;

public String getMyData()
{
    return myData;
}
public  void setMyData(String myDataa)
{
    myData=myDataa;
}}
```

BaseAdapterActivity.java

```
public class MyBaseAdapterActivity extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<ListDataActivity> list =new ArrayList<ListDataActivity>();
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

public MyBaseAdapterActivity(Context context,ArrayList<ListDataActivity>list)
{
    this.list=list;
    this.context=context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyViewHolder myViewHolder;

    if (convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_addlist,parent,false);
        myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
    }else {
        myViewHolder =(MyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    ListDataActivity listDataActivity = getItemId(position);

    myViewHolder.mydata.setText(listDataActivity.getMyData());

    return convertView;
}
private class MyViewHolder{
    String mydata;

    public MyViewHolder(View item)
    {
        mydata=(ListView)item.findViewById(R.id.myData);
    }
}}
```

AddListActivity.java

```
public class AddlistActivity extends Activity {
ListView lstName;
Button btnAdd;
EditText edtName;
String myData;
Context context=AddlistActivity.this;
ArrayList<ListDataActivity>list=new ArrayList<ListDataActivity>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addlist);

    lstName=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_name);
    btnAdd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    edtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
    getDataInList();

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myData=edtName.getText().toString().trim();
        }
    });

    lstName.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapterActivity(context,list));
}
private void getDataInList()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < myData.length();i++)
    {
        ListDataActivity listDataActivity = new ListDataActivity();
        listDataActivity.setMyData(myData[i]);
        list.add(listDataActivity);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For storing your value from edit text to listview on button click, go through the following step on your button click:

1. get the text from editText and store in a String.

   ```
       String myText=editText.getText().toString().trim();
   ```
2. then save it to your arraylist(data structure which you will use to feed data to your listview via your BaseAdapter).

   ```
         ArrayList<String> stockList = new ArrayList<String>();
           stockList.add(myText);
   ```
3. mainly this arraylist will have your data of edittext and then you have call   adapter.notifydatasetchanged();

thanks